# Подскажите, как прописать текст-подсказку в поле формы html?

Tags: html

Нужно добавить в поле формы текст-подсказку, как здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте атрибут placeholder.

```
<input placeholder="В чем заключается ваш вопрос? Будьте конкретны." value="">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
placeholder="твой текст"
```

Добавляешь этот атрибут к **input**